# RefineryCMS images upload not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, refinerycms, refinery

I've got a website running on RefineryCMS for some time already. However there's one thing I cannot figure out. Images uploaded via CMS do not work in the production environment. It works fine in development on my local machine, but in production on the server it does not work.

This issue has been discussed before but none of the solutions I found helped to resolve my issue.

The image is uploaded to the public folder correctly, I can find it when I enter the path of folders and name of the image itself to the browser. The image is there, but it seems the app cannot decode the hashed URL that is generated for the image.

The app is running on a custom VPS on digitalocean with Ubuntu, nginx and passenger. I'm deploying via capistrano if that matters.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Probably figured this out by now but I just ran into the same issue and realized I hadn't installed imagemagick yet.

For some reason I was thinking that came standard now on Ubuntu but it isn't.

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: You sir are a hero.